# Expected ; after method prototype error

Tags: objective-c

I always get this error on various separate projects of code and I just can't figure out what the error is. I'm using Xcode 6, and the Objective C language. The error is:

> Expected ; after method prototype.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

//the error is on the next line 
-(IBAction)number1:(id)sender{
SelectNumber =   * 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot put method bodies in an `@interface` block.  You can only put them in an `@implementation` block.

Xcode's template for `UIViewController` subclasses puts both a class extension (`@interface ViewController () ... @end`) and an implementation block (`@implementation ViewController ... @end`) in the `.m` file.  You have accidentally defined your method in the class extension.  You need to move it down to the implementation block.  You should end up with something like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)number1:(id)sender{
    SelectNumber *= 10;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You define prototypes within the "`@interface`" section of a .h and/or .m file.

Those should just be one line method declarations ending with a semicolon.

You should move the whole function implementation into the "`@implementation`" section, which is what you're doing up there.  Just change "`@interface`" into "`@implentation`" and you'll compile okay.

If you want your function to be exposed to other classes & objects, put your method declaration in your .h file.